# Comparing two dates for daily reward in iOS game

Tags: iphone, ios, date, nsdate

I was implementing a 'daily reward' method in order to give some coins every day in my game.

I have a json that contains the actual date and time.

The issue is that I don't know how to compare the dates.

Here is my code -

```
@implementation ItemRewardManager

+(NSDate *)dateFromUTCTimeStamp:(NSString *)dateString{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [df setTimeZone:gmt];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDate forKey:@"lastDatePlayed"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)getData
{
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dateUrl]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *keys = [jsonObjects allKeys];

    // values in foreach loop
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [jsonObjects objectForKey:key]);
    }
}

+(void)dailyReward{
    NSLog(@"llega al daily");
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];

    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDatePlayed"] isEqualToString: dateString])
    {
        NSLog(@"Actual date is the same as json date");
        UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         message:@"You have win 5 coins! Come back tomorrow for more."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
}
@end
```

So, when I open my app and call this method, my app crashes for some reasone.

I think the problem might be on the comparison of the two dates.

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong?

Comment: I don't think that giving rewards is a job of the client but one of the server. But have you already debuged your "lastDatePlayed"? you save it as NSDate object and compare it to a NSString. could be a reason. by the way, these results will never be equal as far as I see :)

Comment: @geo You're right. Im not comparing something logic. I don't know the logic of the daily reward by now... can you help me?

Comment: I would recommand to let the server doing the calculation for the reward, just sending you a notification that you can request it now. I would also let the server send a *unix-timestamp*, easier to work with. Also for comparing dates use the answer of @torip3ng . And adding values to a date you can use the `NSDateComponents` with `NSCalendar`. (`NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:date];` ) i.e.

Comment: @geo I will try comparing the dates, because another person made me a json with the date. So I wont be able to modify it.

Comment: I don't think that you should compare two dates -- you should consider each on his/her own merits.  And somehow "rewarding" the "better" date seems way out of line.  (When did SO become a dateline anyway?)

Answer (score 3):

Use following.

```
if ([date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderedSame)
```

date1 and date2 are `NSdate` objects.

Comment: I don't understand, should I replace ´date1´ with ´dateString´and ´date2´ with ´[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDate forKey:@"lastDatePlayed"];´ ?

Comment: not strings. You have NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; and lastDate object. If you stored lastDate as string convert it to dateObject like NSDate *now = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDatePlayed"]];

Comment: Nope, crashes. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d587e10'

Answer (score 3):

NSDate has methods for comparing dates.
Here they are:

> isEqualToDate: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given
>   object is an NSDate object and exactly equal the receiver.
>
> `- (BOOL)isEqualToDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`
>
> laterDate: Returns the later of the receiver and another given date.
>
> `- (NSDate *)laterDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`
>
> earlierDate: Returns the earlier of the receiver and another given
>   date.
>
> `- (NSDate *)earlierDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`

Comment: Like this?
if ([now isEqualToDate:serverDate] == TRUE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Actual date is the same as json date");
        UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         message:@"You have win 5 coins! Come back tomorrow for more."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
        return;

    }

Comment: These methods are needed to compare and get a date object.
For a simple comparison:if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. It may help you

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // current date
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDatePlayed"]]; // server date 

NSComparisonResult result; 

result = [now compare:newDate]; // comparing two dates

if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
    NSLog(@"now is less");
else if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
    NSLog(@"newDate is less");
else
    NSLog(@"Both dates are same");
```

Comment: What should I put on the `"xxxx"`? this:`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDate forKey:@"lastDatePlayed"];` ?

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDatePlayed"]`. Put this and try

Comment: `NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastDatePlayed"]];` full code

Comment: not a miskate, a warning that tells me `Class method +dateWithString: not found (return type defaults to id)` I think it is `dateFromComponents:` or something like that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32339/discussion-between-developer-ios-and-vergmort)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *ServerDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:@"03/01/2013"];
[dateFormatter1 release];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:ServerDate];
int diff=interval/1440;
```

This is implemented code.